# Returning relative path of anchors in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mootools

Say you have a link with a relative path that looks like this:

```
<a id="link" href="/folder/filename.php">Link Text</a>
```

and you try to grab that href using Mootools code like this:

```
$('link').get('href');
```

That will return `/folder/filename.php` in every browser but IE which literally inserts the domain for you, returning `http://www.domain.com/folder/filename.php`.

Is there a way around this? If not, how can I reliably grab everything but the domain in all browsers? String matching will be a pain because this site is currently being tested on three different domains, not to mention the different people doing local testing with who knows what combination of localhost, port number, and whatever else.

Comment: i copied your two lines of code into http://jsfiddle.net/ and it worked for me. I was using FF3.6 and IE7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably best off testing to see if the URL starts with a URI scheme plus domain. This avoids the odd-but-perfectly-valid case where the domain exists in the path.

```
var href = $('link').get('href'),
    prefix = location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname;
if (href.indexOf(prefix) === 0) {
    href = href.substring(prefix.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try making this into a function

```
function GetRelative(selector)
{
    var url = $(selector).get("href");
    var hostname = window.location.hostname;
    var index = url.indexOf(hostname);
    if (index == -1)
        return url;
    else
        return url.substring(index);
}
```